# How to find a possibility of match in Naive Bayes Classifier?

Tags: classification, statistics

My math level is very very poor so I can't get the statistics.
Can anyone explain in simple words?
I.e. if I have frequency data:

```
Apple:
    Colors:
        Green = 3, Red = 2, Orange = 0;
    Shape:
        Sphere = 5, Ellipsoid = 0.
Orange:
    Colors:
        Green = 0, Red = 0, Orange = 5;
    Shape:
        Sphere = 5, Ellipsoid = 0.
```

I have many so fruits with frequencies, of course.
**How can I get a possibility for object `{Color: Red, Shape: Sphere}` that it's an apple?**

Comment: It's a bit confusing to use orange as a fruit and color. May I suggest you change the orange fruit to another, like pear?

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret, yeah, it's a good idea

Comment: In fact there is a shortcut here. I just noticed there are no red oranges. So we can get an answer to this particular question without doing any calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ and $O$ be the events apple and orange (fruit). Let $R$ and $S$ be the events red and sphere.

By Bayes' law,
$$\Pr[A | R \wedge S] = \frac{ \Pr[R \wedge S | A] \Pr[A] }{ \Pr[R \wedge S] };$$
$$\Pr[O | R \wedge S] = \frac{ \Pr[R \wedge S | O] \Pr[O] }{ \Pr[R \wedge S] }.$$
By total probability adding to 1, we also have
$$\Pr[A | R \wedge S] + \Pr[O | R \wedge S] = 1$$
and therefore
$$\Pr[R \wedge S | A] \Pr[A] + \Pr[R \wedge S | O] \Pr[O] = \Pr[R \wedge S]$$
so
$$\Pr[A | R \wedge S] = \frac{\Pr[R \wedge S | A] \Pr[A] }{ \Pr[R \wedge S | A] \Pr[A] + \Pr[R \wedge S | O] \Pr[O]}.$$
By the Naive Bayes assumption of independence of features conditioned on class,
$$\Pr[R \wedge S | A] = \Pr[R | A] \Pr[S | A];$$
$$\Pr[R \wedge S | O] = \Pr[R | O] \Pr[S | O].$$
Putting it together, we get
$$\Pr[A | R \wedge S] = \frac{\Pr[R | A] \Pr[S | A] \Pr[A] }{ \Pr[R | A] \Pr[S | A] \Pr[A] + \Pr[R | O] \Pr[S | O] \Pr[O]}.$$

Now plug and chug. From the data $\Pr[R | A] = \frac{ \Pr[R \wedge A] }{ \Pr[A] } = \frac{2}{5}$, etc. Note: I am assuming the empirical distribution is the true distribution, an assumption your teacher probably expects you to make but not made in practice.

Comment: Thank you for detail answer but does `Pr[R&A]` mean `Pr(R)*Pr(A)`? Sorry, I am really a noobie.

Comment: No. It means the probability of $R$ and $A$ simultaneously, or the probability of a fruit being a red apple. This is the number of red apples divided by the total number of fruits, or $\frac{2}{10}$.